# "Section type conflict" in arm embedded, what is it?

Tags: c, embedded, arm, stm32

I am getting an error for this:

[image]
Can any one guide me on this? What sort of error is this. What are some generic possible errors causes for this. I am asking about Section type conflict.

What I find on Google is the people saying different things about their specific platforms, compilers.

I am using GCC, STM32F429I, and VSTAR OS (RTOS).

```
C:\Users\munullah\eclipseworkspace\onsvr\vstar_os\applications\sample\gen
\STM32F429I\GNU\Os_Lcfg.c:530:58: error: 
Os_IsrCAT1PlatformConfig causes a section type conflict with 
Os_SC1_EPSSOS_IIK_400_STM32F429I_GNU         
CONSTP2CONST(Os_IsrPlatformConfigType,OS_CONST,OS_CONST) Os_IsrCAT1PlatformConfig[1];

C:\Users\munullah\eclipseworkspace\onsvr\vstar_os\applications\sample\gen\STM32F429I\GNU\Os_Lcfg.c:53:21: 
note: 'Os_SC1_EPSSOS_IIK_400_STM32F429I_GNU'
 was declared here
 CONST(uint8,OS_VAR) Os_SC1_EPSSOS_IIK_400_STM32F429I_GNU = (uint8)0U;

                   ^
../../BuildSystem/makefile:283: recipe for target 'objs/STM32F429I/GNU/Os_Lcfg.o' failed
make: *** [objs/STM32F429I/GNU/Os_Lcfg.o] Error 1
```

P.S: You may see the image properly by Right-click and then view image.

Comment: Please copy-paste the *complet* and *unedited* error into your question. It's impossible to read the text in the image.

Comment: Copying out of windows dos boxes in just one of the many pains with trying to do serious work on that platform; if I recall it is done with some secret right click menu on the window title bar or something like that.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : I have added a P.S. note. CMD does not allow me right click. I can type the error If you're still unable to see the image.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have added text.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : you are right [This helped me](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/windows_dos_copy.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: This is hard to even read, but my suspicion is that you have something treated as constant in one place and "ordinary" in another and that causes a conflict with a linker rule which puts constants in flash but other things in (likely initialized) ram storage.

Comment: For clarity, post text *as text* - not a picture of some text! For Windows console [like this](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-copy-and-paste-windows-command-prompt.htm)

Comment: Or just re-type the entire thing, exactly as shown, if you cant cut and paste,

Comment: @user263210 To copy the text: Click on the icon on the left side of the title bar, select Edit, then select Mark. Use your mouse to highlight the text you wish to copy, then click Enter. That will copy the text to the Clipboard allowing you to paste it elsewhere.

Comment: Looks like Os_SC1_EPSSOS_IIK_400_STM32F429I_GNU defined twice. Also, can you dump strings from C:\Users\munullah\eclipseworkspace\onsvr\vstar_os\applications\sample\gen\STM32F429I\GNU\Os_Lcfg.c at line 530 and C:\Users\munullah\eclipseworkspace\onsvr\vstar_os\applications\sample\gen\STM32F429I\GNU\Os_Lcfg.c at line 53?

Comment: @Tanuki : That was a linker issue, i believe. Some segments were not made properly. I previously put a general STM32F4 Linker file to build. Now I optimized it for my OS.

Comment: @user263210, so it works now and the issue is over?

Comment: @Tanuki : I am working on it. I commented some things and also corrected the linker script. Actually its a four week task for platform and compiler porting of a sample VSTAR application code. After adding necessary files when I will debug the elf file, then It will say all... (I did wrong or not and other bugs)